# Unable to find implicit macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am using a macro for materializing a string from the given typename, implemented in the `TypeInfo` typeclass. I have an `EntityName` typeclass, that uses the name provided by a `TypeInfo` and formats it.
Finally, I want to use `EntityName` in my `Usage` objects to derive names for the `A` class.

So, in a separate compilation unit I have the following simple macro bundle:

**playground/TypeInfoMacros.scala**

```
package playground

import macrocompat.bundle

import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

@bundle
private class TypeInfoMacros(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def matTypeInfoImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag]: Tree = {
    val A = c.weakTypeOf[A]
    val name = A.typeSymbol.name.decodedName.toString.trim

    q"new TypeInfo[$A] { def name = $name }"
  }
}
```

In my main compilation unit, I have the `TypeInfo` typeclass with the implicit macro materializer:

**playground/util/TypeInfo.scala**

```
package playground.util

import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait TypeInfo[A] { def name: String }
object TypeInfo extends TypeInfoInstances {
  def apply[A](implicit ti: TypeInfo[A]): TypeInfo[A] = ti
}

trait TypeInfoInstances {
  implicit def materializeTypeInfo[A]: TypeInfo[A] = macro playground.TypeInfoMacros.matTypeInfoImpl[A]
}
```

The `EntityName` typeclass looks like this:

**playground/EntityName.scala**

```
package playground

import playground.util.TypeInfo

trait EntityName[T] {
  val value: String
}
object EntityName {
  def apply[T](implicit entityName: EntityName[T]): String = entityName.value
  implicit def entity[T: TypeInfo]: EntityName[T] = new EntityName[T] {
    override val value: String = implicitly[TypeInfo[T]].name // not too complicated formatting :)
  }
}
```

I created an implicits object for mixing in all my instances in the project:

**playground/implicits.scala**
    package playground

```
import playground.util.TypeInfoInstances

object implicits extends TypeInfoInstances
```

Finally the usages:

**playground/Usages.scala**

```
package playground

class X

object UsageA {
  import playground.util.TypeInfo

  EntityName[X] // works!
}

object UsageB {
  import playground.implicits

  EntityName[X] // could not find implicit value for parameter entityName: playground.EntityName[playground.X]
}

object UsageC {
  implicit val instance = new playground.util.TypeInfoInstances{}

  EntityName[X] // could not find implicit value for parameter entityName: playground.EntityName[playground.X]
}
```

My diagnosis:
To me, it looks like if the `TypeInfo` trait is not explicitly imported, the materialization is not taking place. I find it strange, because if I change `materializeTypeInfo` to a normal function, say

```
implicit def materializeTypeInfo[A]: TypeInfo[A] = new TypeInfo[A] { def name = "something "}
```

then all 3 are working.

I am using Scala 2.11.12

1. Is this a bug?
2. How can I use `TypeInfo` without explicitly importing it?

Comment: Decided to use `TypeTag`s instead.